# Is it possible to find out the total size of all existing npm modules in the npm registry (f.e. npmjs.org)?

Tags: node.js, npm, repository, offline

I need to create offline npm repository and therefore this question arose.
So i wanna to know the total size based on size of the *.tgz for each package and it should include every available version for each package.

Comment: This sounds like an XY issue. Do you want to know the size of the registry? Do you want to know how to crawl through every package tar archive? If you can focus your question, "How do you find the size of a CommonJS Package Registry?" I think the answers would be valuable. I'd add a bounty

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and quite easily: open https://registry.npmjs.org/ and take a look at sizes.

At this moment it's 285 GB.